# Geth Sync failed

Tags: blockchain

I started to sync Ethereum using command geth --syncmode "fast" on my windows system. It was taking so much time so i have stopped sync and used the following command.

geth --syncmode "fast" --cache=2048. However getting error synchorizatin failed.

can anyone have an idea about this error?

Comment: What is the error? Syncing can take a long time if you are behind a NAT, also only SSD are supported for syncing by geth and parity.

Comment: it works fine after restarting sync. thanks